# Subscription, Plan, User Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, subscription

My brain is getting tangled. I have users and they can have one plan and one subscription. I am using ryan bates example for subscription and have everything working except I don't know how to get the user_id into the subscription

here is my subscription controller.

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def subscription_params
      params.require(:subscription).permit(:plan_id, :email, :user_id)
  end
end
```

here is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :videos
  has_many :votes
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :videos_with_votes, :through => :votes, :source => :video
  has_many :videos_with_favorites, :through => :favorites, :source => :video
  has_one :subscription
  has_one :plan, :through => :subscription
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "80x80#" }

  def voted?(video)
    votes.exists?(video_id: video.id)
  end

  def favorited?(video)
    favorites.exists?(video_id: video.id)
  end

end
```

here is my plan model

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users
end
```

here is my subscription model

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :plan_id
  validates_presence_of :email
end
```

Comment: Do *not* allow users to pass `user_id` as a parameter to then map to your model. That's a huge security hole. Are you using `Devise`? Do you have access to `current_user`?

Comment: thanks. i did not know that. I will remove from strong params. I am using devise, how can i use the current_user to pass into subscriptions?

Comment: sorry that did not work. I thought maybe i could do @subscription = current_user.subscription.build(subscription_params), but that did not work either

Comment: I apologise, should be `current_user.build_subscription(subscription_params)`.

Comment: Wow. That's it!! I am not familiar with this way to do this. Any good explanation or documentation I should look at? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Nothing will get you more familiar with this stuff than running through the Getting Started guides. Here's the particular section that discusses the `build_` association method: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference